# VS 2013 can't find lib file from Boost toolkit

Tags: regex, testing, visual-c++, boost, shared-libraries

I'm working from the "Boost Getting Started on Windows" guide.
I'm running the code:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat("^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)");

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'   C:\local\boost_1_55_0\example\example\LINK  example
```

Well, of COURSE it can't open the file: libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib
because the name of the binary is libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib

I added the additional link directory, but it's not looking for the right file.
How can I tell it to look for the right file?  BTW, using VS Express 2013, windows 7.

Comment: It is looking for the right file, you installed the wrong ones. :) | Boost libs tagged with `vc100` are meant for Visual C++ 10.0, which is part of MSVS 2010. The default compiler used by MSVS 2013 is version 12.0, which means tag `vc120` in the boost library name.

Comment: boogers.  rebuilding libs and will see if I can fix it that way. tx

Comment: Yip. That was it. Tx again.